# button click not working inside if statement

Tags: if-statement, checkbox, onclick

Dears...this is part of my chatbot.when user click button nothing happens.please help

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message



if user_input := st.chat_input("You:"):
   st.write(f"User: {user_input}")


    
   bot_reply = "Test bot reply"
   st.write(f"Bot: {bot_reply}")
   button_info_list = [{"title": "Title", "payload": "Foo"}, {"title": "Another title","payload": "Payload"}]
       
   for button_info in button_info_list:
       button_title = button_info.get("title", "")
       payload = button_info.get("payload", "").lstrip("/")
       if st.button(button_title):
               st.write("After clicking {button_title")
```